# Ribbon is not enabling in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am developing an outlook add-in application and I added a `ribbon.xml` file in my project and if I run the project my ribbon control is not enabling in my outlook.

Rather I add the ribbon visual designer and changed the ribbon type `Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer` then I am able to see my ribbon,

What am I missing? 
I've uploaded a my sample solution [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B6FA583DCB6667E!928&authkey=!APSdsZOjXh1KKKI&ithint=file%2Czip)

Comment: Please post the relevant code on site.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any UI errors when using the ribbon xml markup? See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) for more information.

See [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx) for the detailed steps.

When do you return the ribbon XML markup? Do you check the paramater passed to the GetCustomUI method?

Comment: wow! Eugne, thanks a lot. Yes I was getting some UI issue, I have given id and idMso for tab, now I removed id and it is showing charm. Thanks again.